# MSAccess Form Search-Button conflicts with Edit-Button

Tags: vba, ms-access, search, command, edit

I'm new to this forum and quite new to Access. I have the following problem. I've created an Form/Subform to edit the Data of a Query.  Two Controls seem to be in conflict in my code.

"Search_Order" is an unbound text field. If text is entered and enter is pressed the corresponding fields of a query are shown. The code looks like the following:

```
Set rs_Search = Me.RecordsetClone
rs_Search.FindFirst "[OrderNumber]=""" & Search_Order & """"
If rs_Search.NoMatch Then
MsgBox "Sorry, no such record '" & Search_Order & "' was found.", _
vbOKOnly + vbInformation
Else
Me.Recordset.Bookmark = rs_Search.Bookmark
End If
rs_Search.Close
Search_Order = Null
Set rs_Search = Nothing
End Sub
```

The second command "ButtonSetOrderDetails10" should create a RecordsetClone of the Subform "sfrmChangeOrderDetails" and change the Value of the Field "OrderStatus" to the Vlaue of "10".

It has this code:

```
Private Sub ButtonSetOrderDetails10_Click()
Dim rs_Status_Change As DAO.Recordset
Set rs_Status_Change = Me.sfrmChangeOrderDetails.Form.RecordsetClone
With rs_Status_Change
Do While Not .EOF
.Edit
.Fields("OrderStatus") = 10
.Update
.MoveNext
Loop
End With
rs_Status_Change.Close
Set rs_Status_Change = Nothing
End Sub
```

I've looked both codes here up and modified them to the needs of my database. Both codes work fine so far, but unfortunately only once.

My problem is that as soon as I hit the Button "ButtonSetOrderDetails10" I can't do the same trick with a different order. I can search for the other order, it is displayed but the Button "ButtonSetOrderDetails10" does not work anymore. If I close the Form and reopen it, it works again.

It would be great if someone can give me a hint what I'm doing wrong here.

Best regards, Ferdi

Comment: Instead of opening a RecordsetClone, could just run an UPDATE action SQL on the subform dataset. `CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE ChangeOrderDetails SET OrderStatus=10 WHERE OrderNumber='" & Me.OrderNumber & "'"`. Why not have order number selected with combobox? Are you not using autonumber primary keys?

Comment: Hi June,

thank you so much for your help. Your code (of course) works and makes much more sense than what I've crafted there.

Regarding your Question:
I know what a combo box is and I've seen it before. But my knowledge is too limited to see why it is superior? Can you briefly explain?

No I don't have an autonumber as a Primary Key for the Order Number. I red before that this would be good. Nonetheless, from my gut feeling I would like to go for a Sequential Number. So e.g. an Order in 2020 has the Order-Number O-2020-00001... I can't elaborate exactly why but I somehow want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am surprised even works one time. With DAO recordset need to read dataset into memory before it will be able see records for edit otherwise just sees EOF and the loop doesn't run. Try:

```
rs_Status_Change.MoveLast
rs_Status_Change.MoveFirst
With rs_Status_Change
```

Don't even need to declare/set/close a recordset object.

```
Private Sub Search_Order_AfterUpdate()
With Me.RecordsetClone
    .FindFirst "[OrderNumber]='" & Me.Search_Order & "'"
    If .NoMatch Then
        MsgBox "Sorry, no such record '" & Me.Search_Order & "' was found.", _
        vbOKOnly + vbInformation
    Else
        Me.Bookmark = .Bookmark
    End If
End With
Me.Search_Order = Null
End Sub

Private Sub ButtonSetOrderDetails10_Click()
With Me.sfrmChangeOrderDetails.Form.RecordsetClone
    .MoveLast
    .MoveFirst
    Do While Not .EOF
        .Edit
        .Fields("OrderStatus") = 10
        .Update
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With
End Sub
```

Could really simplify code by running an UPDATE action SQL.

```
Private Sub ButtonSetOrderDetails10_Click()
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE ChangeOrderDetails SET OrderStatus=10 WHERE OrderNumber='" & Me.OrderNumber & "'"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi June,

thank you so much for your help. Your code (of course) works and makes much more sense than what I've crafted there.